# How to add superscript in PyQt5 combobox?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I try to add to combobox list of units with superscripts. One of these is cm^-1. How can I put it as text?
`self.cbUnit.addItems(["unit 1", "unit 2", "cm-1"])`

Answer (score 1):

Found solution.

`self.cbUnit.addItems(["unit 1", "unit 2", "cm\u207B\u00B9"])`